# How to optimize a matrix multiplication in MATLAB?

Tags: optimization, matlab, matrix

Can I somehow optimize this formula? I evaluate it many times and it takes much time...

`w` - 1xN double

`phis` - NxN double

`x` - Nx2 double

> sum(w(ones([size(x, 1) 1]),:) .* phis, 2)

Comment: also, which of N, x, w and phis vary on each call?

Comment: Matlab **IS** optimized for matrix multiplication - that is what the "Mat" part of the name stands for! So if you use the matrix multiplication `*` as shown by the other Jonas below, instead of reinventing it using `*.`, `sum` and all the other stuff, it should be a lot quicker ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're taking the scalar product of each row of `phis` with `w`. You can do this easily using linear algebra.

```
out = phis * w';
```

This [matrix multiplication](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/arithmeticoperators.html) saves you calls to `sum`, `ones`, and `size`, which should make your code a lot faster. Furthermore, linear algebra operations are often very fast in Matlab, since that's what the program is historically optimized for.

Comment: I don't think that this will work correctly. I should remap w to size of phis and than calculate their sum for each row.

Comment: @Yekver: This will **exactly** work, since a [scalar product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_product) between a matrix and a vector does exactly what you call "remap w to size of phis and calculate their sum". And in MATLAB, a scalar product is as simple as the other Jonas showed you...

Comment: @Jonas: how about adding a link to http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/arithmeticoperators.html to your answer? The question title says "matrix multiplication", and that help page explains that `*` is matrix multiplication...

Comment: @Jonas Heidelberg: Good suggestion. I keep forgetting that not every Matlab user knows linear algebra.